# Grails 3 with Spring Data Solr - returning a HighlightPage<T> as Json/XML

Tags: grails, spring-data-rest, grails-3.0, spring-data-solr

I have integrated Spring Data Solr into a grails 3 app and most things work fine.  My 'ModuleRepository' exposes most of its magic restful methods and returns nice HATEOAS style json responses.

However I am running into issues with @Highlighted queries. Take the one below, if I run it directly via http://localhost:8080/modules/search/findByDescriptionContaining?description=mat

```
interface ModuleRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<Module, String>{

    @Highlight(prefix = "<b>", postfix = "</b>")
    HighlightPage<Module> findByDescriptionContaining(@Param(value = "description") String description, Pageable pageable)



}
```

results... notice no highlighting meta info/snipplets:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "modules" : [ {
      "name" : "Mathematics",
      "description" : "a very matematical course",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/modules/101"
        },
        "module" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/modules/101"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "name" : "Computer Science",
      "description" : "A mixture of maths and science",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/modules/103"
        },
        "module" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/modules/103"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/modules/search/findByDescriptionContaining?description=mat"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 2,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

whilst I do get results, the json is missing all the 'snipplet' fields related to highlighting.  I also had the exact same problem in a Spring Boot app but got around it there by writing my own controller which called an @Autowired moduleRepository and just returned the results. So I then tried this in my grails app:

```
class SimpleController{

        ModuleRepository moduleRepository

        static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

        def highlight(){
            respond moduleRepository.findByDescriptionContaining("cou", new PageRequest(0,10))
        }


}
```

however when I hit this controller method I get the following json

```
{"allFacets":[null],"class":"org.springframework.data.solr.core.query.result.SolrResultPage"{"message":"Internal server error","error":500}
```

In the logs I see this exception:

```
ERROR org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - IllegalAccessException occurred when processing request: [GET] /simple/highlight
Class org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GenericJavaBeanMarshaller can not access a member of class org.springframework.data.domain.Chunk with modifiers "public". Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException: Error converting Bean with class org.springframework.data.solr.core.query.result.SolrResultPage
    at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:184)
    at grails.converters.JSON.render(JSON.java:119)
    at grails.views.mvc.renderer.DefaultViewRenderer.render(DefaultViewRenderer.groovy:97)
    at grails.artefact.controller.RestResponder$Trait$Helper.internalRespond(RestResponder.groovy:188)
    at grails.artefact.controller.RestResponder$Trait$Helper.respond(RestResponder.groovy:98)
    at uk.ac.lse.coursefinder.controller.SimpleController$$EPfjBU3s.highlight(SimpleController.groovy:33)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GenericJavaBeanMarshaller can not access a member of class org.springframework.data.domain.Chunk with modifiers "public"
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

Is there an easy solution to this without having to manually process/convert HighlightPage into my own custom DTO ?